# What's the right way to create error messages that get returned in an Express request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, express

I have a function called `a` that accepts a callback, which is invoked with an error if there is one.

`a` is invoked in an Express route request. If there is an error, the error should be the response of the request.

```
function a(cb) {
  cb(new Error('Some error message'))
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  a(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      res.json(error, 400)
    }
    res.send('No error')
  })
})
```

I have looked into the code for Express, and it appears that `res.json` will stringify my `error`. However, the result of this is an empty string:

```
> var e = new Error('Some error message')
undefined
> JSON.stringify(e)
'{}'
> e.message
'Some error message'
```

There are ways I could get my route to return the error message here, such as converting the error object `toString` in my route. However, I would like to know what the best practice is for formatting error messages in Node APIs, and whether that changes things here. Should I format my error messages differently, or should I just handle the `Error` object in the route, such as:

```
res.json({ error: error.message }, 400)
```

Comment: Some details for why the e.message is missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) routes can use a third argument `next` that can be used to either skip the current route by just calling `next()`, or to pass on errors by calling `next(err)`.

Try using:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  a(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      next(error);
    }
    else {
      res.send('No error')
    }
  });
});
```

For more information, check out http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 6):

To add to @steveukx's answer, you can specify an error handler in express, by `.use`ing a function with arity of four.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.json(500, {
    error: err.message
  });
});
```

Which will be called whenever you do `next(err)`.
See [the docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling).

Comment: This is deprecated, you should now use: `res.status(500).json(error)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't now what your response look like, when no error occurs, but this is how I usually handle JSON responses:

```
function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({
            success: false,
            error: err.message
        }, 400);
    }
    else {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            data: data
        });
    }
}
```

Try to wrap this in a extra middleware/function. Keep the signature of the functions similar to standard node style. (First parameter error, following parameter the actual data.) This way it is much easy for the client to process you responses, because all you have to do is look into the `success` field.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. I'll wait a bit before accepting this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to throw an error is to use an informative error instead of a generic error. Generic errors should only be thrown if the informative error itself fails for some reason. Here's a generic handler I use demonstrating custom errors and falling back to a generic error:

```
fpToExpressJson = async (response, next, fp, args) => {
  const oResponse = await fp(args).catch(err => err);

  if (!oResponse) {
    return next(createError(404));
  }

  if (oResponse.errorCode) {
    // Good job developer! You threw a descriptive error.
    try {
      return response.status(oResponse.errorCode).send(oResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
  }

  return response.json(oResponse);
};
```