# Why is a Javascript Error object not treated as an object by expressjs

Tags: javascript

I have a node/express backend. In my backend I create an error object if there is an error, but when I try to send it in the response it is not there. I was able to make my code work by building a new object in the response, but I would like to know why it didn't work.

The relevant code is:

```
var error = new Error('some error message')

app.send({error}) // returns {}

app.send({error: error.message}) // returns {error: 'some error message}
```

According to MDN docs, an error object is an object, and we should therefore be able to pass it directly into app.send(). This didn't work in practice, and I would like to be able to explain why. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify)

Comment: It's the same issue, but I was looking for the why instead of the how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `app.send` converts the value to JSON. [`JSON.stringify` only considers (own) **enumerable** properties](https://es5.github.io/x15.12.html#x15.12.3) and `message` is not enumerable:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(new Error('foo'), 'message');
Object {value: "foo", writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```