# Output full error object in node.js

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, command-line

There are several places where error objects are used, like when you catch errors or in the case of exec an error object can be passed back by a child process.  When you attempt to log that information, not quite all of it makes it out.

I've tried the following:

```
console.log(error);
console.log(error.stack);
console.log(util.inpect(error, true, null));
```

All these options seem to output a different set of incomplete data.  Is there a one line way to make sure I always get all the data I need to see from errors displayed or do I need to use all three of these lines (are there even more statements I need to add?)?

Comment: `to make sure I always get all the data I need to see from errors` - what do you need to see?

Comment: Well, I would like to see stack trace, error message, that kind of thing.  But, since I have found 3 ways to find error information, I'm left wondering what wonderful, enlightening data that is available I didn't even know about because for some reason beyond me it prints out different with different methods.  In short, I don't trust that I even know about all the information that is there at this point.  In short, I want it all.

Comment: You can add arbitrary information to the error object. So, I don't think there is one-way oneliner to cover all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert many JavaScript objects to strings using JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(error, ["message", "arguments", "type", "name"]));
```

EDIT:
Updated to reflect the point made by @laggingreflex in the comment...

Comment: `Error` is actually one of the objects that `JSON.stringify` doesn't work well with. This will output just an empty object `{}`. [You'll have to manually specify properties for it to work `JSON.stringify(err,["message","arguments","type","name"])`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify/26199752#26199752)