# NodeJS Mongoose Schema 'save' function error handling?

Tags: node.js, validation, error-handling, mongoose

I am having a problem outputting an error to the user using res.send(err), which is being called in the callback of the Mongoose User Schemas 'save' function. I would like to note that when I use console.log(err), it show's the expected error (such as username is too short), but res.send is outputting '{}' in PostMan when sending a request with POST values that should cause an error.

Also I am wondering if I should be doing input validation in my router or in my Mongoose user schemas .pre function?  Putting validation there seems correct, as it keeps my Node router file much cleaner.

Here is the code in question...

app/routes/apiRouter.js

```
var User = require('../models/User');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
apiRouter.post('/users/register', function(req, res, next) {


    var user = new User;
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            //User saved!
            res.json({ message: 'User created' });
        }
    });

});
...
```

app/models/User.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var validator = require('validator');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true} },
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    if (!validator.isLength(user.name, 1, 50)) {
        return next(new Error('Name must be between 1 and 50 characters.'));
    }

    if (!validator.isLength(user.username, 4, 16)) {
        return next(new Error('Username must be between 4 and 16 characters.'));
    }

    if (!validator.isLength(user.password, 8, 16)) {
        return next(new Error('Password must be between 8 and 16 characters.'));
    }

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, false, false, function(err, hash) {
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
    var user = this;
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance, it looks like you are using express. When an object or array is passed to `res.send()` (like in the case an error occurs), it defaults to using `JSON.stringify` on the object/array and sets the content-type to `application/json`. (Ref: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send). The message property of an Error object is not serialized when it is passed through `JSON.stringify` because it is defined with `enumerable` being `false`.

Ex.

```
 $ node
 > var err = new Error('This is a test')
 undefined
 > console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
 {}
 undefined
```

[Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify) has some examples of how to make sure the `message` property (and others if that is what you would like) are included.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to respond.  I am going to check out that other SO question you linked, and if it solves the problem I'll mark your reply as the answer.

EDIT:  I just checked it out and yeah, it seems this answer is what I should be doing before calling res.send(err)

'var stringifyError = JSON.stringify(err, ["message", "arguments", "type", "name"]);  res.send(stringifyError);'