# Why does JSON.stringify on TypeError return an empty object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm using node 4.2, and I'm catching an error and using JSON.stringify on it. For most objects, this works fine. But when a [TypeError: callback is not a function] is thrown, it returns an empty object. if I console.log it directly, it works fine.

Mozilla's page says:

> Boolean, Number, and String objects are converted to the corresponding primitive values during stringification, in accord with the traditional conversion semantics.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(err)) // outputs {}
}
```

Comment: Stringifying an empty object should work, I think ?

Comment: And why wouldn't you log it directly, or like `console.log('error : ', err)`

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(TypeError, null, 2))` gives me undefined

Comment: Why are you trying to stringify the error? Just log it directly like @adeneo suggested.

Comment: @Daniel_L - probably because `TypeError` is a native function

Comment: `JSON.stringify(Function.prototype.call)` <- undefined

Comment: Often times, objects are thrown that will show [object Object] if not strigified. There are other errors than TypeErrors. I could do some case checking and handle per case, but I was also just wondering why the behavior was occurring.

Comment: Just because probably: http://jsfiddle.net/oykzgjkr/

Comment: IMHO, [this is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18391400/2542172) best answer, how you can stringify Error object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you use `stringify` on a TypeError, you're stringifying an object with no [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) properties.

So if you do

```
var typeError = new TypeError("hey")
for(var prop in typeError) {
  console.log(prop) // this does not run
}
```

When you log using `console.log`, you're using `valueOf`, so

```
var typeError = new TypeError("hey")
typeError.valueOf()  // TypeError: hey(…)
```

Also, an error knows how to turn itself into a string, so this works too:

```
var typeError = new TypeError("hey")
typeError.toString() // "TypeError: hey"
```

---

If you want to log the properties of an object you can't see using a normal log, you can [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) the object.

When you do it on the `typeError`, you'll see that it has a `message` property:

[image]