# How to get property out of JavaScript object which is only appearing in console.log() but not in JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, console.log

I'm getting an error object back from my SQLite database. When I display it with `console.log(err)`, I get:

> { records: { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: showcaseUsers errno:
>   1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' } }

Yet when I display it with `JSON.stringify(err)`, I only get:

> {"records":{"errno":1,"code":"SQLITE_ERROR"}}

I want to get the error message `no such table: showcaseUsers` in a string.

The only way I have found how to do this is with this:

```
const errorText = console.log(data);
```

But this also outputs the data to the console, which is undesirable.

**How can I either (1) stop console.log from outputting its content to the console, or else (2) get the error message in a string some other way?**

NOTE: I am in Node at this point and not in a browser, so it doesn't seem that the answer at [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log) is helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)

Comment: "The only way I have found how to do this is with this:

const errorText = console.log(data);"
remove the console.log?  `const errorText=data;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify missing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487441/json-stringify-missing-properties) I think this should help you ;) This looks exactly like your object!

Comment: @Mukyuu I can do `const errorText=data` and then output `console.log(errorText)` but errorText is `typeof` is object, not string, length is undefined.

Comment: you will probably find that the additional error string is being held in a _non-enumerable_ property of the error object.   You should be able to extract that.

Comment: which precise sqllite module are you using?

Comment: @Alnitak I'm using the npm package `"sqlite3": "^4.0.2"`

Comment: @EdwardTanguay you might wish to rephrase the question to reflect what the real problem was (i.e. getting the data out of the error object) as opposed to your intended solution (intercepting the console).  Notwithstanding you did ask how you could "get the error message in a string in some other way" the rest of the question as written is a classic "XY problem".

Comment: Thanks, @Alnitak, I rephrased the title so it better reflects the content and answer.

Comment: p.s. you could also have used `err.toString()` to get "`Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: showcaseUsers `"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to intercept the `console` at all - you will find the entire error message in `err.message`, albeit still prefixed with "`SQLITE_ERROR:`"

It's a non-enumerable property of the `Error` object hence why it doesn't appear in the JSON output:

```
let sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
db.run("UPDATE foo SET bar = 1", (err, res) => {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(err));
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

with output:

```
{ stack:
   { value: 'Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: foo',
     writable: true,
     enumerable: false,
     configurable: true },
  message:
   { value: 'SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: foo',
     writable: true,
     enumerable: false,        <<---------
     configurable: true },
  errno:
   { value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true },
  code:
   { value: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
     writable: true,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true } }
SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: foo
```

Comment: thanks for your info  "  a non-enumerable property of the Error object " 

I had stayed up too late to find out what weird thing happened with the message of Error Object

Now I have more information to dig in more, thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

Issue is wrongly formatted JSON, which must be `key:value` pairs. If `value` in `key:value` is a string then it should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

> { records: { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: showcaseUsers errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' } }

In the absence of proper `value` (`value` in your case has datatype `String`), `JSON.stringify(err)` tries to coerce it to JSON based on colon `:` as separator between `key` and `value`. [Available datatypes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types)

Here is a correction, I have just enclosed it in double quotes, and formatted it (formatting is optional, helpful for legibility).

```
{ 
    records: { 
        Error: "SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: showcaseUsers errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'" 
    } 
}
```

Actually it should be formatted (see placement of single quotes) like so

```
{ 
    records: { 
        Error: 'SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: showcaseUsers',
        errno: 1, 
        code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
    } 
}
```

**Update:** It's imperative to store properly formatted data in database in the first place. If you missed it then you are left with manually parsing data you are getting from SQLite.

**Helpful resources**

- [How to store JSON object in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603621/how-to-store-json-object-in-sqlite-database#answer-16603687)
- [Use the new JSON extension for SQLite with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603621/how-to-store-json-object-in-sqlite-database#answer-33784064)
- [Library to query JSON1, FTS3, and FTS4 fields in Android](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android)

Comment: Right, but I get this object from the SQLITE database so I have to deal with it as it is. How can I access this wrongly formatted portion of the object?

Comment: It's imperative to store properly formatted data in database in the first place. If you missed it then you are left with manually parsing data you are getting from SQLite.

Comment: This has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with the format of the data in the database.   When the OP says he "gets this object from the SQLITE database" he means that it's an object _generated by the database engine_, not one _stored in the database_.