# dir-compare throws empty error inside VSCode extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, dir-compare

When running the `dir-compare` package `compare()` method inside a VSCode Extension it is not succeeding, while it does from a regular node script.

It doesn't seem to output any error. What is happening here? Is there a way to find the underlying error? Is this even possible? How do I proceed?

The code below results in outputting `err {}`.

```
const path1 = 'C:/a';
const path2 = 'C:/b';

try
{
    dircompare.compare(path1, path2)
        .then(res => terminal.sendText( 'echo "res ' + JSON.stringify( res ) + '"' ))
        .catch(error => terminal.sendText( 'echo "E2 ' + JSON.stringify( error ) + '"' ));
}
catch(e)
{
    terminal.sendText( 'echo "err ' + JSON.stringify( e ) + '"' );
}
```

Comment: I found out that only the sync methods in `file` work in a VSC extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to `stringify()` and log a caught error object directly, but using `err?.message` the error can be shown.
See: [Why are my JS promise catch error objects empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513493/why-are-my-js-promise-catch-error-objects-empty)

The error that appeared was `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading compare)`

Apparently importing `dir-compare` directly was not working

<s>`import dircompare from 'dir-compare';`</s>

Instead importing its methods:

`import { compareSync } from 'dir-compare';`

Then calling the method directly:

`compareSync( path1, path2 );`