# Ionic - navigator.geolocation returns empty error object

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a small app that relies on geolocation. I use the following code to get the current location from the device:

```
var options = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 300000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(result) {
  console.info(result);
}, function(error) {
  console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
}, options);
```

However, this **always call the error callback** with an **empty error object**:

```
1     123317   error    {}
```

There is no code nor message, just an empty object. Also interesting is that the error callback is called **immediately**, no matter what I set as timeout.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

The result is the same weather I run it in the emulator or directly on my phone. If anyone has any idea on how to fix this, hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the error object returned is a special object. Using `JSON.stringify` does not consider inherited properties. This is especially true if you are using Chrome or Safari.

```
$cordovaGeolocation
.getCurrentPosition()
.then((resp)=>{
  $scope.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
  $scope.lon = resp.coords.longitude;
}).catch((error)=> {
  $scope.errm = error.message;
  $scope.errc = error.code;
  console.log(error.code+" "+error.message)
});
```

You can use this code to view the error code and message. If you want to view complete object you can use [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391400/4374566%22SO%20Answer%22) to do so.

As of the errors, there are several ones like need for secure origins or a wifi connection that might be limiting the same.

PS: This holds true for the Geolocation object also.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code

`var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:5000, maximumAge: 0 };`