# How to let react electron ignore undefined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

[image]
[image]

React electron on windows, if `A` is null, call `A.test` will make the application stop working, then the user has to close the application and restart it.
How to let `react` ignore the error, and continue work. The code has many `A.test`, I can't write everywhere `if(A) A.test`.
If this can't be resolved, can I print the error on the web view? So I don't have to remote visit the user's computer to see the console error.

Comment: Electon is just a backend server app on node and chrome based engine on frontend. Don't wait from browser to ignore errors. Just write clean, good code with checking `if (something.MemberList) { then do operation }`  You've to handle possible situations to avoid errors interrupting code execution.

Comment: Wrap the code with `try` `catch`

Comment: @num8er No, your code will stop the software as well, `if(something&&Object.keys(something).includes('MemberList')){` is right! I have too many code like this.

Comment: @Oram I use `ErrorBoundary`, but it can't print the error code like `A.test is undefined`

Comment: `if(something && something.MemberList)` or `if(something && something.hasOwnProperty('MemberList'))` is enough. ok. but then what's Your problem? just make sure Your app works correct and You'll not get that errors. Find that issue and fix it.

Comment: @num8er `if (!self.sessions.map(e => e ? e.UserName : '').includes(userid)) {` like this, the `e` can be null, then the software stop working util the user restart it . I mean the code is too much, and this can't be a fatal error, how to make the software continue working, but react will white screen, the user can't click any more.

Comment: @Gank unfortunately You cannot make it continue to work. It's not nodejs (backend) part of code where You can do: `process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => { /*  do nothing */ });`

Comment: maybe You want this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249886/is-it-possible-to-catch-exceptions-of-renderer-processes-in-electrons-main-proce

Comment: @num8er It works good in js code, but in the view code: `this.state.ServerNameList.map((value,key) =>
                                <option value={key} key={key}>{vadlue}</option>
                            )` The `vadlue` will make the react white screen as well.

Comment: What is `vadlue`? Whether is it `value`?

Comment: You should show the code for the component that is failing. Otherwise, you're only going to get generic suggestions, "use try/catch", "use error boundaries" etc.

Comment: The better way is using a component lifecycle method to handle an error view. you can see [my naswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53419941/6877799)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*NOTE*

I think the solution is to use [react error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html), as suggested in the console.

You already pointed out that you're using error boundaries, so after testing your scenarios [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gatsbimantico/c83zas9b/) I believe your implementation might be incorrect.

---

Given a similar implementation for `ErrorBoundary` in the docs:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: '' };
  render() {
    return this.state.hasError ? (
      <span>Oops! Something went wrong:<br />{this.state.hasError}</span>
    ) : this.props.children;
  }
}
ErrorBoundary.getDerivedStateFromError = (error) => ({ hasError: error.toString() });
```

This component will render the fallback when any of its **children** breaks.

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI

It will look similar to:

```
<MyReactApp>
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <ChatContent />
  </ErrorBoundary>
</MyReactApp>
```

Now any error in `ChatContent` will be catch by `ErrorBoundary` giving you the opportunity to render the fallback like:

```
Oops! Something went wrong:
ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

> The code has many A.test, I can't write every where if(A) A.test

But why? You can use [some editor](https://superuser.com/questions/1003790/how-to-find-and-replace-lines-in-multiple-files-using-notepad) for multi file editing.
So you can replace `A.test()` to `safeTest(A)` function.

```
export const safeTest = (Obj) => {
 if (Obj) {
  Obj.test();
 } else {
  // Any action you want
 }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the comments on the question it also makes reference to this scenario: `map((value,key) => <option value={key} key={key}>{vadlue}</option> )` which is the opposite to safe code. The user is probably working in a project coded by third parties with untrustable code quality.

Comment: 3rd-party code - probably. But I didn't see anything about it. What I really read, was `The code has many A.test, I can't write every where if(A) A.test`

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to offer an answer to your question because I don't see your project codes, but if your react version is 16 you can use a special component lifecycle method that name is [`componentDidCatch`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html).

Inside this method you will have these values:

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
  // Do something with error and info
}
```

Even you can use `setState` inside this method and show you want. I think this method can help you for your second desire, the printing `error` in web view.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to favor using [default props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops). You can set a value for the component to assign to a prop if the prop is passed in undefined. For example, if your component depends on an array nested within an object, you could set that value as an empty array by default. This is especially handy when your component depends on an array of results from an API call, but the component renders before the request finishes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the minimal effort to **catch all the unhandled errors** from both main and renderer processes within Electron as well as **showing them to the user via a dialog**, the easy way is to use [electron-unhandled](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-unhandled) which does exactly that:

After having installed it (`npm i electron-unhandled`), in both your main and renderer entry files (likely their root `index.js`), you just have to add, at the beginning:

```
const unhandled = require('electron-unhandled');

unhandled({ showDialog: true });
```

Now, that being said, it's a good practice to use a global error catcher but it's a really bad one if you use only that. You should try covering your error handling more accurately, at least method by method:

- `.then() { ... }.catch(err => ...)` for your promises,
- `(..., (err, res) => { if (err !== null) { ... } ... )` for your callbacks,
- `try { ... } catch(err) { ... }` for non-async or `await`-based code code parts.

*And, as a side-note, I myself created a [dependenciless library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rorre) to make it safe and easy to create a global errors dictionary in order to well-organize your errors but there are other alternatives if this one doesn't fit your needs.*

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best possible solution to this would be surrounding your `A.test` in `try` and `catch`. In this case what you can do is `catch` the error is `A` is `null` and perform some error page from your side incase you want it or just keep the error silent incase you dont want to perform any operation and suppress the error and continue execution.

You can also wrap `A.test` in a function with `try-catch` and use that function instead of `A.test`. In this way you can avoid multiple `try-catch` block and you can handle the error as per your requirement here.