# How to stringify Error in js?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Is it not possible to stringify error using JSON.stringify?

Also, Object.keys(err) wouldn't show any keys present with Error object.

Other observation: Error object has non standard property "stack" which I am trying to access. Error.prototype.stack provides with stack trace. In my attempts to stringify properties of Error(name, message and stack), any help is appreciated!

Following is the output from Chrome.

```
  > var err = new Error
    undefined
  > err
    Error
       at <anonymous>:1:11
   JSON.stringify(err)
  > "{}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify)

Comment: try `err+""`. is that what you want?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

How about try something like err.toString()

Comment: Doesn't print the whole stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
    JSON.stringify(error.stack)
```