# Express Js not sending error object on res.json()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
getUser: function(req, res){
    Model.getUser({}, function(error, models){
         if(error){
              let response = {
                  code: 'ERR0001',
                  msg: 'Facing issues while ....',
                  err: error
              }
              res.json(response);
          } else {
              res.json(models)
          }
     }
};
```

Above code is working fine for all positive scenarios. But for error scenario I am not getting complete error message instead it shows 'err: {}'.

I have already registered JSON parser with Express app object. 
Response I am getting in POSTMAN console in case error is

```
{
  code: 'ERR0001',
  msg: 'Facing issues while ....',
  err: {}
}
```

As per my requirement it should display something like:

```
{
  code: 'ERR0001',
  msg: 'Facing issues while ....',
  err: 'ERROR: whatever exception occurred on database operation...' 
}
```

Please help me to understand cause of this issue.

Comment: `console.log` the `error` before to check that it's what you expect.

Comment: Moreover it's almost never just a string. If you just want the string of the error message, then call `error.toString()` on the assignment.

Comment: Thanks Neil, error.toString() solved 50% problem. now it returns main error message, but not full stack trace. Though its not required to be returned to front-end but still if there is any solution.

Answer (score 5):

Express is stringifying your JSON response when you use `res.json()`.

However, because the `Error` object doesn't get handled by `JSON.stringify()` as you would expect, you're not seeing the content of it; like the stack trace property for example.

For details on what's happening with `JSON.stringify()` and the `Error` object, check out this other stack overflow answer (I won't duplicate that here):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391400/2387067

So, using a variation of that answer, I will do this when I want to send back a Javascript `Error` object to the client from Express:

```
function replaceErrors(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Error) {
        var error = {};

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).forEach(function (key) {
            error[key] = value[key];
        });

        return error;
    }

    return value;
}

function getPureError(error) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error, replaceErrors));
}
```

and then make a call to it in my response like this:

```
res.status(500).json(getPureError(error));
```

The call to `getPureError()` stringifys the `Error` object and gets all of the properties because of the call to `replaceErrors()`. It then parses it back to a pure object. That pure object plays nicely with Express when the `.json()` call is made so you get all of your properties that you were expecting. It is a bit wasteful but you get the result you're looking for.

This results in my seeing the full, `Error` object; stack trace and all.

When I first encountered this problem, I was doing this:

```
res.status(500).json(error);
```

and I was getting back `{}` in my response on the server. It took me a bit of time to sort out what was happening there. I originally thought that I wasn't chaining that `json()` command incorrectly but I was. The actual problem was that the `Error` object doesn't behave like other objects with `JSON.stringify()` as described above.

I hope that helps you or at least someone else after all this time!