# "__zone_symbol_currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}

Tags: ionic2, facebook-oauth

I am getting this error

```
"__zone_symbol_currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}
```

while login facebook from my hybrid application. I have used

> ng2-cordova-oauth

plugin to achieve facebook login. My code look like.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {OauthCordova} from '../../../node_modules/ng2-cordova-oauth/platform/cordova';
import {Facebook} from '../../../node_modules/ng2-cordova-oauth/core';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-facebook',
  templateUrl: 'facebook.html',
})
export class FacebookPage {

  public oauth: OauthCordova;
  private provider: Facebook;

  public constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform) {
    this.oauth = new OauthCordova();
    this.provider = new Facebook({
      clientId: "1807864452579635",
      appScope: ['id','story','picture','link','type','full_picture','message']
    });
  }

  public login() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.oauth.logInVia(this.provider).then((success) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(success));
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this on a project I was working on too.  The problem turned out to be that the `ng2-cordova-oauth` dependencies weren't installed.  Specifically we had to run:

- `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`
- `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`
- `cordova prepare`

You may also have to whitelist your site using the information found at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Edit: You can't use `ng2-cordova-oauth` from the browser.  You have to use a device or a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

> note that it is unlikely for anyone to see the original error in this code since it in part depends on external dependencies

You can use

```
    JSON.stringify(error,Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));
```

to get a clear description of the error you getting, because The __zone_symbol_currentTask is a property inserted into the Error object by Angular and JSON.stringify does not output the Error object's own properties (by default)

see also: [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify)