# How to store a javascript error object with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say we have an error object like this:

```
const error = new Error('Error');
```

How can I store this in mongo? Tried to store it in a field with the type Object (Even tried the type Mixed) but it just stores an empty Object.

```
const UserLogSchema = new Schema(
  {
    ...
    error: {
      type: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const UserLog = mongoose.model('UserLog', UserLogSchema);
```

Adding the error:

```
const userLog = await UserLog.findOne({ _id: userLogID });

userLog.error = new Error('Error');

await userLog.save();
```

When we try to get the error later:

```
const userLog = await UserLog.findOne({ _id: userLogID });

console.log(userLog.error)
```

It just prints `{}`. But the actual error is not empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it sufficient solution to serialize the error object and store as a json string?

```
error = new Error('ahhhh');
errorJson = JSON.stringify(error, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error));
console.log(errorJson);
// output: {"stack":"Error: ahhhh\n    at <anonymous>:1:7","message":"ahhhh"}
```

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify), you could also use [serialize-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-error) package.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create a schema in mongoose for storing error with two properties like

```
{
  errorDescription: {
    type: 'object',
    required: true
  },
  timestamp: {}
}
```

something like this, and whenever you got an error access this scema and save it it the DB `schemaName.save('errroObject',function(obj){})`. This will save you information.