# convert object to string using JSON.stringify show empty object

Tags: javascript, json, string

I'm trying to convert object to string using JSON.stringify and I get empty object

```
console.log('typeof',typeof e,' e value is',e, 'JSON stringify is',JSON.stringify(e))
```

the error message when I try to print

**typeof** object  **e value is** Error: Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
**JSON stringify is** {}

[image]

Comment: @ManuallyOverridden `console.log` is variadic — you can pass multiple objects, which are separated by a `,`.

Comment: It looks like `e` is an error object. In node, stringifying an error results in `{}`. Not sure how you are running your code.

Comment: @ManuallyOverridden even I do let a = JSON.stringify(e) and I print a I get empty object..

Comment: @Mark_M how can I print error object? I want use it to string and show in client side

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object `e` is an error object. When you try to stringify that you get `{}` in chrome and node. Safari shows a little more info.

```js
let e = new Error("hello")
console.log(typeof e)
console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
```

You can test for errors with:

```js
let e = new Error("Some error happened")
if (e instanceof Error) {
  console.log("Error:", e.message)
 }
```