# Error Boundary does not give access to error if it is an instance of Error class

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I came accross a weird behavior. 
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/93483/). When using React 16 error handling mechanisme, namely Error Boundary, I noticed the `error` parameter was empty. Upon further investigation I realised it was only the case when throwing an Error object like so :

`throw new Error('The world is very strange')`

However, when throwing the error this way :

`throw 'The world is very strange'`

The error will be available in `componentDidCatch`.

Please, someone, enlighten me. 
I wish to continue using `new Error` because it is recommended to use it and it should give access to file and line number of throw.

Let's take a look at the code.

```
class Boundary extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
       this.setState({
        error,
        info,
      })
    }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
       return (
       <div>
         {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
       </div>)
    }
    return this.props.children;
   }
}

class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
  // Why and what should i do ?
    throw 'This will be available in the error parameter'
    throw new Error('This one will not')
  }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <Boundary>
      <div>
        <Component />
      </div>
    </Boundary>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, update the question with relevant code from your fiddle. Links may become dead, while the question should be understandable without reading external resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing strings is discouraged because an error is conventionally an object, preferably an instance of `Error`.

There is no problem with throwing `Error`. There is a problem with how it's processed:

```
  if (this.state.error) {
     return (
     <div>
       {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
     </div>)
  }
```

Since `error.message` is non-enumerable, `error` is stringified to `{}`. This is expected behaviour. `JSON.stringify` shouldn't be relied on as all-round representation of objects - this is what dev tools console is for.

Current representation could be fixed by extending `Error`:

```
class HumanReadableError extends Error {
  toJSON() {
    return `Error: ${this.message}`;
  }
}
```

and

```
throw new HumanReadableError('This will not be available');
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is actually available. The problem is that [`JSON.stringify` doesn't serialize `Error` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify), and since that's what you're using to display the error, it appears like the error is empty.

[Here's an updated version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wq0c7ae/) that explicitly outputs `state.error.message`, and it works.