# Node.js - Try Catch Error Not Being Returned

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, try-catch

i have written a node.js api using the express framework. I am using await and async. I catch the asynchronous function in a try catch block. However in the catch(err) method the err is not being returned.

```
try {

            const job = await this.jobRepository.functionDoesNotExist();

            if (job.success === false) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    success: false,
                    status: 404,
                    data: job,
                    message: "Failed to retrieve job"
                });
            }

            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                status: 200,
                data: job.data,
                message: "Successfully retrieved job"
            });

        } catch (err) {

            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                status: 500,
                data: err,
                message: "The server threw an unxpected errror"
            });

        }
```

In the above example i am deliberately calling a function that does not exist so that it throws an error.

The response i get is below. It is hitting the catch block, but the error is not being added to the data object.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "status": 500,
    "data": {},
    "message": "The server threw an unxpected errror"
}
```

However, if i move the below line out of the try catch block. The console will throw the following error.

```
    const job = await this.jobRepository.functionDoesNotExist();

"error":{},"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: this.jobRepository.functionDoesNotExist is not a function\nTypeError: this.jobRepository.functionDoesNotExist is not a function\n    at JobController.<anonymous>
```

So my question is, why is this error not being displayed in the response when the call is made within the try catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, The error object is not `JSON.stringify()`-able. [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify)

To get the stack trace however, you can use `err.stack` like so:

```
    return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        status: 500,
        data: err.stack,
        message: "The server threw an unxpected errror"
    });
```