# Why exception doesn't have properties in the $exceptionHandler function and how to workaround this limitation? DataCloneError

Tags: angularjs, exceptionhandler

Using AngularJs v1.5.7, I'm having quite some trouble trying to log the exception.
The issue seem to be with the type of the exception.
This object is somehow not a normal object with properties.
Here is a code sample with what I have attempted so far and the result for each attempts.

```
MyApp.config(['$provide', function ($provide)
{
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', 'logsService', function ($delegate, logsService)
    {

        return function (exception, cause)
        {
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            try
            {

                //Attempt #1 : throw because exception isn't an object.
                logsService.addLog(exception);

                //Attempt #2 : Log the hardcoded object with both properties
                logsService.addLog({a:'Some test', b:'Ok'});

                //Attempt #3 : log an empty object because exception has no property 
                var log = {};
                for (var property in exception)
                {
                    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property))
                    {
                        log[property] = exception[property];
                    }
                }
                logsService.addLog(log);

                //Attempt #4 : Log the message, but doesn't log all possible properties that exception could have.  
                logsService.addLog({ message: exception.message});
            }
            catch (ignore) { }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

N.B : I can't change the `logsService`.
So far, I didn't find anything about this on google.

Why does `exception` has no properties and how to work around this limitation?

### Edit :

I think I've pinpoint a little more the issue. The exception object is probably not clean and have functions or others things that can't be cloned. This give the following error in the log service.

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore'`

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#Things_that_don%27t_work_with_structured_clones)

> Error and Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.

```
    //Attempt #5 : log an empty object because exception has no property.
    var cleanedException = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(exception));
    logsService.addLog(cleanedException);
```

Is is what the exception show when inspecting it in the watch.
[image]

Comment: See [AngularJS $exceptionHandler Service API Reference - Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler#example-). It shows how to overwrite the default `$exceptionHandler`. The default implementation simply delegates to `$log.error` which logs it into the browser console.

Comment: @georgeawg Like you stated, I've tryied overwriting the default implementation but the exception still doesn't have properties and the problem remained the exact same.

Comment: @georgeawg Error is fine, I've added an image what the inspector show about it. But I think the issue is about `Error and Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.`

Answer (score 0):

To copy an [Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) to a plain JavaScript object:

```js
e = new Error("Example");

plain = { message: e.message, stack: e.stack };

console.log(plain);
```

Then it can be cloned for a Web Worker.

Comment: Thanks, I could have done this from the start, but refrained to do so because I've seen cases when there is more properties than just `error` and `message`. My code doesn't need to know what is inside the exception, it just need to log whatever is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because error can't be cloned as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunhandledrejection) which is quite suttle.

> Error and Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.

So others have ran into related issue [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18391212/4625305) and they found a work around using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` has been the way to go for me because all possible properties will be logged.

```
     //Attempt #6: Log all properties
     var cleanedException = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(exception, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exception)));
     logsService.addLog(cleanedException);
```