# Why is this Firebase Function Promise not returning the correct Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

This is a test Firebase Function I'm writing:
I already know that ref.child(uuid) does NOT exist in my Realtime DB.

```
ref.child(uuid).once('value')
    .then((user) => {
        if (!user.exists()) {
            console.log("Throwing, User not found")
            throw new Error("Error: No record with this UUID in Database");
        }

        //Get the node for the given provider (twitter, google or facebook)
        if (user.child(provider).exists())
            return (user.child(provider).val().status)
        else
            throw new Error("Error: Login node does not exist for this provider");
    })
    .then((result) => res.status(200).json({status: result}))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({error_msg: error}));
```

Output

```
Throwing, User not found

400, {"error_msg": {}}
```

So the `throw new Error()` line is run, but the catch is somehow not getting the error message from the 'error' parameter.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Error` constructor contains two properties `message` and `name`, therefore change:

```
{error_msg: error}
```

into this:

```
{error_msg: error.message}
```

For reference check the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: Worth noting that this is because the various properties of an Error object are not enumerable and therefore are ignored by `JSON.stringify(someErrorObject)`. If you want to get more info, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212) has some interesting discussion on the topic and how to get around it.