# destructuring of the orignal error to return invalid data of mongodb errors with an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, error-handling

I'm using  Error Handling with Express and I used  to return invalid data of MongoDB errors with an array

I used

```js
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    
    let error = { ...err };

    if (error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);
    if (error.code === 11000) error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(error);
    if (error.name === 'ValidationError')
      error = handleValidationErrorDB(error);

    sendErrorProd(err, res);
  }
```

but it does not work for the process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

because of let (error = { ...err };)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `let error = { ...err };`? (That's not destructuring, for one thing. It's rest notation.)

Comment: If the problem is that it doesn't work in production, your production environment would appear not to support object rest notation, which was added in ES2018. If you upgrade the version of Node in the environment to anything tolerably recent, it should start working.

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"?

Comment: I want to show all of(CastError,ValidationError,11000) not one by one

Comment: it works with my with this

Comment: else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //

    if (err.name === 'CastError') err = handleCastErrorDB(err);
    if (err.code === 11000) err = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(err);
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError')
      err = handleValidationErrorDB(err);

    sendErrorProd(err, res);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `err` have enumerable properties? My guess is [it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18391212/1048572), so the object spread syntax won't copy anything into the object literal. You might want to simply use the original `err` object, and I think your code should be

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    let error;
    if (err.name === 'CastError')
        error = handleCastErrorDB(err);
    else if (err.code === 11000)
        error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(err);
    else if (err.name === 'ValidationError')
        error = handleValidationErrorDB(err);
    else
        error = { ...err };

    sendErrorProd(err, res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked with my like this

```js
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //

    if (err.name === 'CastError') err = handleCastErrorDB(err);
    if (err.code === 11000) err = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(err);
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError')
      err = handleValidationErrorDB(err);

    sendErrorProd(err, res);
  }
```

but the output looks like this

```js
{
    "status": "fail",
    "message": "Duplicate field value: \"The Snow Adventurer2\". Please use another value!"
}
```

and that's only 11000 error, I have another error with CastError & ValidationError.

I need all errors to show in one message.

this's all code

```js
const handleCastErrorDB = err => {
  const message = `Invalid ${err.path}: ${err.value}.`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const handleDuplicateFieldsDB = err => {
  const value = err.errmsg.match(/(["'])(\\?.)*?\1/)[0];
  console.log(value);

  const message = `Duplicate field value: ${value}. Please use another value!`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};
const handleValidationErrorDB = err => {
  const errors = Object.values(err.errors).map(el => el.message);

  const message = `Invalid input data. ${errors.join('. ')}`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const sendErrorDev = (err, res) => {
  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    status: err.status,
    error: err,
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack
  });
};

const sendErrorProd = (err, res) => {
  // Operational, trusted error: send message to client
  if (err.isOperational) {
    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
      status: err.status,
      message: err.message
    });

    // Programming or other unknown error: don't leak error details
  } else {
    // 1) Log error
    console.error('ERROR ', err);

    // 2) Send generic message
    res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Something went very wrong!'
    });
  }
};

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(err.stack);

  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sendErrorDev(err, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    
    let error = { ...err };

    if (error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);
    if (error.code === 11000) error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(error);
    if (error.name === 'ValidationError')
      error = handleValidationErrorDB(error);

    sendErrorProd(err, res);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63862746/edit) instead of posting an answer (unless you've found a solution yourself)

Comment: Sorry @Bergi, but this's my first question in StackOverflow, and I will find a solution myself