# Handling javascript errors in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

Suppose I have the following async function

```
export async function someAsyncFunction() {
  const result = await fetchData();
  return result[0].id;
}
```

In the route I have

```
router.post(
  '/some-path',
  handleErrorAsync(async (req: Request, resp: Response, _err: Errback) => {
    const data = await someAsyncFunction();
    resp.json(data)
  })
);
```

And I have error handling functionalities that do

```
interface ResponseError extends Error {
  statusCode: number;
}

// Middleware to respond with an error when error caught
export function handleError(
  err: ResponseError,
  _req: Request,
  resp: Response,
  _next: NextFunction
) {
  if (err) {
    resp.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err);
  }
}

export const handleErrorAsync = (func: Function) => (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  func(req, res, next).catch((error: Error) => {
    next(error);
  });
};
```

So this works fine if for example `fetchData` has an error response object, but this fails to print error objects when the error is a regular javascript error and instead it just prints `{}` with 500 error.

For example in this line `return result[0].id;` if the result is empty (`[]`), then this would throw `TypeError`, which will be caught by the `handleError` middleware, but then the `.json(err)` part will show only `{}`

Is there a way I can get both the servers errors (which are working correctly) and the internal server errors with that same middleware?

Answer (score 1):

### res.json do  JSON.parse which returns an empty object {}.

I can suggest destructuring the err body.

```js
 resp.status(err.statusCode || 500).json({message:err.message, error:err});
```

This will give you a message for every Native Error

Comment: Thanks! This helped! Another solution was to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-error

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the `toJSON` method of Error.

```js
let a = new Error("hi")

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))

Error.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    const alt = {};
    // get all property
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach((key) => {
        alt[key] = this[key];
    });

    // only get message property
    // alt["message"] = this["message"]
    return alt;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Then just call `res.json(error)`, and you'll get the property of Error.
Because when you call `res.json(parameter)`, express will trigger the `toJSON` method of parameter.
You could read more in [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify)
.
But, I recommend only expose the "message" property in `toJSON` method.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and for the link which led me to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-error and it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using res.send() in the error handler like

```
return res.status(500).send(err.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-error

```
import { serializeError } from 'serialize-error';

  if (err) {
    resp
      .status(err.statusCode || 500)
      .json(serializeError(err));
  }
```