# How to send an error object from content script to background script?

Tags: javascript, exception, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send an error event object from the content script:

```
catch (error) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sender.id, error);
}
```

to the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(msg)
});
```

in order to log it there with the full stack trace and all the relevant data,
but it always arrives as `undefined`.
I tried to `JSON.Stringify` the error and send it in an object, but it arrives as an empty object.

From https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/:
[image]

If I'm sending `error.message` and `error.stack` separately, creating a new `Error` object works fine:

```
let error = new Error();
error.message = msg.message
error.stack = msg.stack;
```

How can I send the error object and receive it as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send the error "as-is", since the error object will not survive the async call - it will have gone out of scope. The reason JSON.stringify doesn't work is that the properties of the error are not enumerable because they belong to the error object's prototype chain - they aren't "owned properties". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify) for a discussion and solution. Basically, you need to copy the properties of the error object to a new object and pass that.