# Why does throwing this error result in a blank response, while others work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, nestjs, httpresponse

I'm doing a project using NestJS, and while developing the service and controller for a component, I was handling errors using try - catch methods and then throwing them. However, I encountered a certain error that I'm unable to throw, as it results in a blank response body, while other works. For example:

This is a (working) function inside my `upload.service.ts`:

```
async saveFile(body, file) {
    try {
      const uploadRepository = getRepository(Upload);
      const result = await uploadRepository.save({
        // assign properties [...]
      });
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      unlink(file.path);
      console.log(error);  // Output 1 
      throw new BadRequestException(error);  // Response 1
    }
}
```

So when I purposely make a Bad Request (by not sending a required value in the request body), I get this in the console: 
(Output 1)

```
QueryFailedError: null value in column "type" of relation "upload" violates not-null constraint
    at new QueryFailedError (%PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (%PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\typeorm\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.js:247:31)
    at step (%PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.throw (%PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:122:57)
    at rejected (%PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  length: 393,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23502',
  detail: 'Failing row contains (51, 15, 2021-03-23 10:52:59.763387, 2021-03-23 10:52:59.763387, example.pdf, application/pdf, uploads\\e0f65f7ab43f1c226b37a9463f3a4745, null).',
  [...]
}
```

And the proper error returned in the response body, using Postman: 
(Response 1)

```
{
    "message": "null value in column \"type\" of relation \"upload\" violates not-null constraint",
    "length": 393,
    "name": "QueryFailedError",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "23502",
    "detail": "Failing row contains (51, 15, 2021-03-23 10:52:59.763387, 2021-03-23 10:52:59.763387, example.pdf, application/pdf, uploads\\e0f65f7ab43f1c226b37a9463f3a4745, null).",
    [...]
}
```

---

Now, this is another function inside `upload.service.ts`:

```
async readFile(res, fileId) {
    try {
      const uploadRepository = getRepository(Upload);
      const found = await uploadRepository.findOne({ id: fileId });

      res.download(found.path, found.originalName);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);  // Output 2
      throw new BadRequestException(error);  // Response 2
    }
  }
```

When I purposely make a Bad Request (by sending a non-existent ID which `uploadRepository.findOne` won't find), I get this in the console: 
(Output 2)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at UploadsService.readFile (%PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\dist\src\components\uploads\uploads.service.js:52:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async %PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at async %PROJECT_DIRECTORY%\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

But a blank object in the response body, though it correctly has the 400 Status code, using Postman: 
(Response 2)

```
{}
```

---

I can tell that the former error, as seen in the console.log output, has an object with more properties. However, I can't tell why I'm unable to return the latter error properly. I have also tried:

```
throw new NotFoundException({ message: error });
throw new NotFoundException(JSON.stringify(error));
throw new NotFoundException(error.TypeError);
```

With no luck, as they show an empty object in the *message* key.

So, **the question is**: How are those errors different, and what's the correct way to send the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question which made me look deep in the NestJS source. So, here's what's happening.

After throwing the `BadRequestException` that was passed a `TypeError` (note that this comes from NodeJS, not NestJS) the `BaseExceptionFilter` catches the error and passes it down to the `ExpressAdapter` (assuming you're using express). There, [on the following line](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.ts#L31), they do:

```
return isObject(body) ? response.json(body) : response.send(String(body));
```

The `body` variable refers to the `TypeError` itself and is an object, so `response.json(body)` is executed.
The thing is, that inside the `response.json` function, the object which was passed to it, gets `stringifed` using `JSON.stringify`.
Since the `TypeError` has no enumerable properties, you get an empty object string `{}` as a result.

If you're wondering *why* that is, take a look at this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50738205/3761628).

So to get around this, you could create your own error object instead of the `TypeError` and pass that to `BadRequestException`.

Comment: The SO-post on the _why_ was very interesting and helpful! Thank you, it allowed me to fix my problem :)

May I ask, what whas your procedure to get to the relevant code in NestJS's source and eventually find the problem?

Comment: Happy to help! Usually I debug into the library's source code using my IDE to see what's really going on. So in your case I created a minimal NestJS project with a controller where I deliberately forced a `TypeError`, set a breakpoint on the throw statement and used "step into" which after a few calls lead me to the `BaseExceptionFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving eol's input from his answer, I wondered "How could I see what the structure of an object is"? and so I came into the [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) method which "*returns an array of all properties (**including non-enumerable properties** except for those which use Symbol) found directly in a given object.*"
After adding `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error));` the output was `[ 'stack', 'message' ]`.

Since the `message` property is a string, what finally worked was:

```
throw new NotFoundException(error.message);
```